# Deduplicate list in Apex? (ApexAction for Flow)

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am competent with Salesforce but far less so with Apex!  Due to flow limitations I am trying to do something with an Apex Action.

I pass to the code below a TASKID.  In turn this code finds other tasks for the associated lead (there will only ever be one WHOID on these) and passes back to flow.

Specifically I need subject to start with OPENED and contain a '-'.  This works fine.

HOWEVER, I want this returned list to flow to ALSO be deduplicated by SUBJECT.  I don't care which Task happens to be returned, just as long as subject is only there once.

How can this code be modified to loop through the SOQL output to de-duplicate based on SUBJECT?

```java
public class tasksListAction {
    //this invocable method takes a single task id from Flow from a record variable
    //and returns a list of tasks.
    //the list of lists is stored as a collection variable in the Flow.
    @InvocableMethod (label = 'SendTasksGet Task' description = 'returns tasks for this lead.')
    
    //this method returns a List of Lists of Tasks to the flow and receives a List of Ids
    public static List<List<Task>> getLeadIds (List<ID> ids) {
        
        //Store in a list the id, closedate and Amounts of opps whose Primary Contact came in the variable "ids"
        //and who have a stage of Clsoed Won and a Close Date of this year
        List<Task> taskis = [SELECT id, subject
                                  FROM TASK
                                  WHERE whoid in :ids
                                  AND Subject LIKE 'Opened%'
                                  AND Subject LIKE '%-%']; 
        //declare a new list of lists of tasks
        List<List<Task>> itemListList = new List<List<Task>>();
        //add the list opps to the list of lists
        itemListList.add(taskis);
        // send list of lists to the Flow   
        return itemListList;        
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which one is returned, building a [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm) with the subject as the key will ensure there is only one value (in this case, a Task) for it. Each `put(key, value)` will overwrite the value if the key already exists. The one callout is that the key is case-sensitive so Subjects with case differences won't be considered equal.

> Map keys of type String are case-sensitive. Two keys that differ only by the case are considered unique and have corresponding distinct Map entries. Subsequently, the Map methods, including put, get, containsKey, and remove treat these keys as distinct

```java
Map<String,Task> tasksBySubject = new Map<String,Task>();

for(Task task : taskis){
    tasksBySubject.put(task.Subject, task);
}

itemListList.add(tasksBySubject.values());
```

If you change your mind and do what some sort of filter for "which" one is picked, the nice thing is you can simply add [ORDER BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) in the query to ensure the last value you put in the Map is the one you want returned (ex. `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC` to return most recent Task with that Subject).

---

In terms of the error you're getting specific to Flow/Invocable Apex

> The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request

It's because you're returning one result (one List of Tasks) yet there's multiple Leads it expects data for (so it'd expect x amount of List of Tasks for x records you're inserting).

For your scenario, making it a bit more complicated, is that you might not return records - so you need to include empty List values into your list of lists.

```java
//Store results by Lead Id and by unique Subject
//Lead Id ==> Unique Subject ==> List of Tasks
//If lead Id exists in Map, add additional returned tasks by subject
Map<String,Map<String,List<Task>>> mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId = new Map<String,Map<String,List<Task>>>();        
for(Task task : taskis ){
    if(mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(task.WhoId) != null){
        Map<String, List<Task>> additionalTasksBySubject = mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(task.WhoId);
        List<Task> additionalTask = new List<Task> { task };
        additionalTasksBySubject.put(task.Subject, additionalTask);
        mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.put(task.WhoId, additionalTasksBySubject);
    } else {
        Map<String, List<Task>> tasksBySubject = new Map<String, List<Task>> {task.Subject => new List<Task> { task }};
        mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.put(task.WhoId, tasksBySubject);  
    }
}

//Buld return output for flow - need a List<Task> for each record in bulk
for(String leadId : ids){
    //If no records found for Lead Id, return an empty list
    //Otherwise, get returned Task records by Lead + unique subjects
    if(mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(leadId) != null){
         List<Task> allUniqueSubjectTasks = new List<Task>();
         Map<String, List<Task>> tasksBySubject = mapOfTasksBySubjectByLeadId.get(leadId);
         //Combine all unique subject task results for one Lead into one list to return one list per Lead Id in the method
         for(List<Task> subjectTasks : tasksBySubject.values()){
             allUniqueSubjectTasks.addAll(subjectTasks);
         }
         itemListList.add(allUniqueSubjectTasks);
     } else {
         itemListList.add(new List<Task>());
     }
}
return itemListList;
```

Comment: To make it more deterministic, ordering by Id would be a good thing to do...

Comment: OK... !  Yes.. got that map working - thanks.  HOWEVER, whilst it's cool in single test, if I bulk load a load of tasks (which is my flow trigger) for the SAME LEAD ID I get this error...  "The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request.".  What is causing that?

Comment: Yes, that is an important part of invocable apex & flow. Each record will be a separate flow interview but your apex invocable is called once (hence you parameter of a list of Ids). It expects you to return a result for each interview aka each Lead record. So, if there's no records to return you also need to return an empty list. Edited answer with an approach.

Comment: Hi Kris - thanks for this.  I took your code and firstly hit the error "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Task.WhoId" so added WHOID to my SOQL query.  However, whilst no fault now, I am not getting the correct answer now - it returns '1' record only from the Apex.  I tried modifying but it's got beyond my skill set presently (albeit I am definitely learning from your code!)  Any thoughts?  And thanks for continued help here!

Comment: I should probably add @KrisGoncalves - this will ALWAYS return something since the lead ID that is passed in actually is derived from a trigger on TASK where SUBJECT starts with OPENED and contains '-' (i.e. same as the SOQL) - hence even if just 1 (the calling task), there will always be at least one task found.  Certainly though your earlier map worked perfectly, the latter only returns 1 record.

Comment: Yes, when building the maps we need to check that the WhoId hasn't already been added (to add more than 1 task). I updated the answer - the logic is in the if/else statement checking if map contains WhoId

Comment: Thanks so much!  I think this is working.  When running in bulk I'm hitting CPU time out, but I think I can be cleverer around how this is called and break down the call via a flow that has waits in etc. to reduce the load.  Certainly though this appears to have overcome the 'bulkification of flows' issue.  I should be good to work with this... will mark answer as correct.  And thanks again @KrisGoncalves as your input has been super useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... might have cracked it by ordering by Subject then looping through and removing from list if current and next are the same...

Does that look right?  A better way?

```
public class tasksListAction {
    //this invocable method takes a single task id from Flow from a record variable
    //and returns a list of tasks.
    //the list of lists is stored as a collection variable in the Flow.
    @InvocableMethod (label = 'SendTasksGet Task' description = 'returns tasks for this lead.')
    
    //this method returns a List of Lists of Tasks to the flow and receives a List of Ids
    public static List<List<Task>> getLeadIds (List<ID> ids) {
        
        //Store in a list the id, closedate and Amounts of opps whose Primary Contact came in the variable "ids"
        //and who have a stage of Clsoed Won and a Close Date of this year
        List<Task> taskis = [SELECT id, subject
                                  FROM TASK
                                  WHERE whoid in :ids
                                  AND Subject LIKE 'Opened%'
                                  AND Subject LIKE '%-%'
                                  ORDER BY Subject]; 
                                  
        //Now loop through and remove where Subject is already seen previously
        for (Integer index = 0; index < taskis.size();) {
    if (index + 1 != taskis.size() &&
                    taskis.get(index).Subject == taskis.get(index + 1).Subject) {
        taskis.remove(index + 1);
    }
    else {
        index++;
    }
}
                          
        //declare a new list of lists of tasks
        List<List<Task>> itemListList = new List<List<Task>>();
        //add the list opps to the list of lists
        itemListList.add(taskis);
        // send list of lists to the Flow   
        return itemListList;        
    }  
}
```

Comment: The map solution is easier and shorter.

Comment: OK... !  Yes.. got that map working - thanks.  HOWEVER, whilst it's cool in single test, if I bulk load a load of tasks (which is my flow trigger) for the SAME LEAD ID I get this error...  "The number of results does not match the number of interviews that were executed in a single bulk execution request.".  What is causing that?

Comment: Flow bulkification. The return list of results must match the input parameter list entries by count and ordering.